# How to interpret Application.Calculation

Tags: excel, vba

I am reviewing some VBA and came across the following code example. I don't fully understand what this does and why it is implemented in this manner. Running the code doesn't explain to me how this affects the macro or the Excel calculations. Can anyone here please explain to me what the Application.Calculation property does and how the following code affects Excel calculations in the macro iterations?

```
Sub example()

Dim CalculationMode As Integer
CalculationMode = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Do While 
  'Generic Do While statement
Loop

Application.Calculation = CalculationMode

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

1. Stores the calculation setting: `CalculationMode = Application.Calculation`
2. Turns calculation to manual: `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`
3. Iterates and does its thing.
4. Restores the original calculation setting. `Application.Calculation = CalculationMode`

---

Here's a testable example of whether formulas update after `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`:

In a new blank sheet, in cell A1 enter the formula `=B1`, and in B1 enter a number like 5.

Testable code:

```
Sub whatever()
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    
    Dim arr(1 To 3) As Long
    arr(1) = 1
    arr(2) = 2
    arr(3) = 3
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Do While i <= 3
        Range("B1").Value = arr(i)
        Debug.Print Range("A1").Value
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

The output in the Immediate Window is:

```
5
5
5
```

not

```
1
2
3
```

However, a counterexample could be the following:

```
    Dim arr(1 To 3) As String
    arr(1) = "=1"
    arr(2) = "=2"
    arr(3) = "=3"

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Do While i <= 3
        Range("A1").Formula = arr(i)
        Debug.Print Range("A1").Value
        i = i + 1
    Loop
```

where the Immediate Window returns:

```
1
2
3
```

i.e. the newly entered formula has been calculated.

Comment: Thank you very much. This answers my questions and I will make sure to accept the answer when I can in a few minutes. Can I please ask you a follow-up question: Given that calculation setting is set to manual prior to the Do While loop, will this cause the model to automatically calculate each Do While loop?

Comment: The exact opposite. It will not automatically calculate.

Comment: Can you confirm if that is also the case for cells where the Do While loop iterations leads to changes in excel formula outcomes? I guess I'm asking if the full Excel model will be retained as static even when the loop changes results in some cells which should flow through the model?

Comment: Does the loop write new formula(s), or change the precedent(s) of the cell containing a formula?

Comment: I added two testable examples but not sure what your setup entails.